# Dreamweaver put to www folder

Tags: file-upload, web-hosting, dreamweaver, godaddy-api

Has anyone experienced this.  I've working with my Godaddy site for years. All of a sudden my uploads are going to my www.  I've checked my manage site info and nothing points to the www folder.  Any ideas

I've call Godaddy, but the rep said there's something wrong with the index.  No hardly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll find that when setting up the server connection details, there is an input box labelled "Root Directory" before the input for "Web URL". The Root directory is the directory or folder on your server in which to connect to and upload/download files.

If this Root Directory input is left empty, then Dreamweaver will use the default root of the web hosting, which is usually www folder.

Make sure all the configuration is correct and change the root directory accordingly.

Comment: I actually dump the page and rebuilt it from the old page.  Not sure what the problem was, but I think it might have gotten corrupted somehow.

Comment: btw, I usually leave the root directory blank, being that it will default to the www folder as you've indicated, but as a result of that, to keep everything consistent, I create a folder with the same name as the server www folder (not the root). In this case 'public_html'.